# Difference between も兼ねて・を兼ねて

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances, verbs, particle-も

Someone asked her friend (in a TV show) 「宿題の答え合わせも兼ねて　勉強会をやりませんか?」 in the sense of "Want to do a study session, and compare our homework answers while we're at it?". Would the meaning change if も兼ねて were replaced by を兼ねて?

BTW, I didn't find a lot of references to this particular meaning of 兼ねて in English-language Japanese study materials online. Is this a common way of using 兼ねて?

Answer (score 2):

I think that も might be a little more natural than を here, because it reflects the idea that it is something "extra" (like an extra activity, an extra benefit, etc.) that is "added" to the main idea of meeting up for a study session.

In your translation, you could incorporate this nuance more directly by adding "also":

> Want to do a study session, and **also** compare our homework answers while we're at it?

Since 兼ねて already has the meaning of doing something alongside something else, I guess を兼ねて would mean more or less the same. However, if the sentence were

> 宿題の答え合わせも**目的に**、勉強会をやりませんか?

replacing も by を would give the sentence a new meaning: namely, that comparing would be the main (or the only) activity for something you're calling 勉強会.

Comment: 宿題の答え合わせ[を/も]して勉強会をやる is a wrong use of the te-form... A better example should be 宿題の答え合わせ[を/も]目的に勉強会をやる or something.

Comment: @naruto Thank you, corrected. (I was hoping to find an example with a verb, but I couldn't come up with a reasonable example...)